# CSS: How to change tooltip position to align to triggering element (rest of code working)

Tags: css, position, css-position

I am trying to **build a tooltip** (without using plugins) **and to position it on the right side of the triggering element** (here an input field), vertically aligned.

So far I have the below (see Fiddle demo). 
This gives me the tooltip I want with the correct layout and content and displays it correctly by click in the input field but **I can't find a way to position it right from the input field** (instead of in the middle of the screen).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltipClose').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.tooltip').removeClass('tooltipShow');
  });

  $('.triggerTooltip').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('div.tooltip').addClass('tooltipShow');
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  bottom: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.tooltipClose {
  background: #028dca;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: -12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 24px;
}
.tooltipClose:hover {
  background: #00507e;
}
.tooltipFooter,
.tooltipHeader {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.tooltipShow {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.tooltip > div {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #028dca;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.tooltip > div:after {
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid #028dca;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: -12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- to see tooltip in the demo -->
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
<input type="text" class="triggerTooltip" />
<div class="tooltip">
  <div>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='tooltipClose'>X</a>
    <p class='tooltipHeader'>Tooltip header</p>
    <p class='tooltipBody'>Tooltip content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:**
    [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwqb9anf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've nearly done all the job.
Here you have an update version of your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwqb9anf/4/)

Here come the small modifications

```
$('.triggerTooltip').on('click', function(){

    // First set the vertical position, use the half of the tooltip height
    $('div.tooltip').css('top', $('div.tooltip div').height()/2);

    // And for the horizontal position we just substract the field's width
    $('div.tooltip').css('left', $(this).offset().left-$(this).width());


    $('div.tooltip').addClass('tooltipShow');

});
```

Hope it's gonna help you

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is great ! I just tested it and it does bring the tooltip closer to the input field but it doesn't position it right next to the input field. What I am looking for is that it appears next to the input with the little triangle appearing at half of the height of the input so that it points at it. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Update: I figured this out. I had to change and add a couple of things to the parameters for top and left but you pointed me in the right direction how to use jQuery for this so I'll accept this answer. :)